# Getting monthly weather means for future climates?

Tags: data, climate

I am trying to generate spatially downscaled (5-10 arcminutes) future climate maps indicating *monthly* mean min and max temp, and precip.  Most people usually need to extrapolate monthly data into daily data (using for eg. [MarkSim](http://gisweb.ciat.cgiar.org/marksim/)).  I just need the monthly.  There are various ways to do this using GCM data available on the internet, but I would like to try doing it using .cli files available from the [DSSAT crop modeling program](http://dssat.net/). I don't know how to get access to these files though.

Do I have to install DSSAT to get the files?

Comment: This seems pretty obscure, have you considered contacting the authors directly?

Comment: Get DSSAT it is free http://dssat.net/772  In DSSAT you need to select externally generated weather data in the simulation controls in order for the model to find the data. http://dssat.net/739

Comment: As for the data import in matlab etc, most programs will have the option to export to csv or something similar in which case reading the data should not be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this website would be useful for future climate data to meet your specific needs:

http://www.ccafs-climate.org/

I haven't downloaded data from here yet, but it does appear to have the very latest available data.

Comment: I am using CCAFS data for future climate projections.  What I need and am asking about here is baseline climate data.  And yes, I can confirm first hand that CCAFS is a great (perhaps the only?) source for GCM generated future climates, downscaled to high resolutions.  But beware of the considerable differences from one GCM's projection to another!  And, at this early stage, be wary of the shortcomings of the current downscaling methods.